# How to save multiple data strings without removing the old ones (in same file)?

Tags: php, forms, post

How to save multiple data strings without removing the old ones (in same file)?

I am using POST to add data from form to TXT file, but it keeps overriding the old data:

```
$txt = "joined_teams.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+'); 

if (isset($_POST['teamname']) && isset($_POST['shortname']) && isset($_POST['1steamid']) && isset($_POST['2steamid']) && isset($_POST['3steamid']) && isset($_POST['4steamid']) && isset($_POST['5steamid'])){ // check if both fields are set
   $txt=$_POST['teamname'].' - '.$_POST['shortname'].' - '.$_POST['1steamid'].' - '.$_POST['2steamid'].' - '.$_POST['3steamid'].' - '.$_POST['4steamid'].' - '.$_POST['5steamid']; 
   file_put_contents('joined_teams.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); // log to joined_teams.txt 
   exit(header('location:http://coprogames.com'));
}

fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the same thing twice. You only need the call to `file_put_contents` and can remove the fopen/fwrite calls. All you need is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['teamname']) && isset($_POST['shortname']) && isset($_POST['1steamid']) && isset($_POST['2steamid']) && isset($_POST['3steamid']) && isset($_POST['4steamid']) && isset($_POST['5steamid'])){ // check if both fields are set
   $txt=$_POST['teamname'].' - '.$_POST['shortname'].' - '.$_POST['1steamid'].' - '.$_POST['2steamid'].' - '.$_POST['3steamid'].' - '.$_POST['4steamid'].' - '.$_POST['5steamid']; 
   file_put_contents('joined_teams.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); // log to joined_teams.txt 
   exit(header('location:http://coprogames.com'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this.

```
file_put_contents('joined_teams.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```